# Mongoose populate reference to own Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema `User` and a field `friends` in there, that references to the `User` schema again, like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

This works fine and I can see the user IDs in the database after setting some of them like this:

```
var test = new User({...});
var admin = new User({...});
var users = [test, admin];

User.find({}).remove(function () {
  User.create(users, function () {
    console.log('finished populating users');
  });
});
```

But now I want to populate the `friends` field when getting a single user and just like in to the documentation, I do this:

```
exports.show = function (req, res, next) {
  var userId = req.params.id;

  User.findById(userId)
    .populate('friends')
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!user) return res.send(401);
      res.json(user.profile);
    });
};
```

But I just get the normal/unpopulated user IDs back!!

I am getting the feeling this is because of the self referencing of the user schema, but the IDs are appearing fine in the database...

The suggested duplicate does not really help me, as I don't even use that much nesting and the problem might just be the **self-referencing of the schema**!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongoose recursive populate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041262/mongoose-recursive-populate)

Comment: Hmm, might be, but I don't have more than this one level. It's just the `populate()` is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out where the problem was. The `user.profile` was a virtual schema from Mongoose. So I extended that:

```
UserSchema
  .virtual('profile')
  .get(function() {
    return {
      '_id': this._id,
      'name': this.name,
      'role': this.role,
      'friends': this.friends
    };
  });
```

Now the populating of the `friends` works!

Answer (score 0):

```
User.findById(userId)
 .populate('friends', ['name', 'email'])
 .exec(function (err, user) {
   if (err) return next(err);
   if (!user) return res.send(401);
   res.json(user.profile);
  });
```

Try populating friends with only required fields(not including 'friends' field) to avoid self-referencing of schema.

Comment: That sounds logical. I guess it tried to populate the 'friends' of the 'friends' too?

Comment: Let me know if that works...n if it works, plz accept/upvote my ans.

Comment: Finally got time to test that, but still doesn't work... :-/

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. See my answer below!