# How to do nested populate in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Post.find()
    .populate("author")
    .populate("comments")
    .populate("commentedBy")
    .sort({date : -1})
    .exec()
    .then(posts => res.json(posts));
});
```

here i am populating the comments from the comment model and then populating the 'commentedBy' from the comment model. The last populating is not working. I am getting {commentedBy: Null, ...}

Comment: Try this `.populate({ path: "comments", populate: { path: "commentedBy" }})`

Comment: Thanks. Its working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose recursive populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041262/mongoose-recursive-populate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes in your code. In your case `comments` are inside `commentedBy` so first you populate `comments` then you populate `commentedBy` inside it.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Post.find()
    .populate("author")
    .populate({ path: 'comments', populate: { path: 'commentedBy' } })
    .sort({date : -1})
    .exec()
    .then(posts => res.json(posts));
});
```

Comment: What will be the syntax if I want to populate two children in 2nd  level, like if i want to populate comments and rating in the fourth line??

Comment: `populate({ path: 'comments', populate: { path: 'commentedBy', populate: [{ path: 'comments '}, { path: 'ratings'}] } })` is this what you're asking?