# Dynamic deep population with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm wondering if you can dynamically deep populate with MongoDB, specifically I'm using mongoose on an express app. I'm trying to build a basic reddit clone. On my Post model, I'm trying to create a reply chain. Replies could become nested, as someone could reply to a reply of a reply. Can I populate down that reply chain? I can only figure out how to populate the first layer of replies. Based on reading the documentation and looking at other anwsers on stack overflow I don't think this is possible, but wanted to put the question out there before I remodeled my data. Here is my Post Model:

```
    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A post can not be empty'],
    },
    thread: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Thread',
    },
    isReply: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    parentPost: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Post',
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

postSchema.virtual('replies', {
  ref: 'Post',
  foreignField: 'parentPost',
  localField: '_id',
});
```

And the thread handler where I'm doing the query and trying to populate the reply chain:

```
exports.getThread = factory.getOne(Thread, 'thread', {
  path: 'posts',
  // Deep populate the replies from each post
  populate: { path: 'replies' },
});

// This is the factory getOne function
    exports.getOne = (Model, modelName, popOptions) =>
      catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
        const query = popOptions
          ? Model.findById(req.params.id).populate(popOptions)
          : Model.findById(req.params.id);
    
        const doc = await query;
    
        if (!doc)
          return next(
            new AppError(`No ${modelName} could be found with that id`, 404)
          );
    
        res.status(200).json({
          status: 'success',
          data: { [modelName]: doc },
        });
      });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoose recursive populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041262/mongoose-recursive-populate)

Answer (score 0):

The desired behaviour is not integrated into mongoose.

I would also advice against a data-structure that makes this necessary. Did you consider other document tree structures (you can find plenty of examples on here or check out the mongodb [docu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/)). I find trees with parent references most useful for comments.

But back to recursive population:

Generally you wouldn't want a query that can return unpredictable amounts of data. So only do this if you otherwise limit the amount of returned docs!

There is another question providing a few examples of custom implementations of recursive relationship population ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041262/mongoose-recursive-populate/48608755))

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the desired behavior using child referencing and then the reccursive population solution in the second link. Thank you for your time